# How to filter out NA with format()

Tags: r, format, na

Please consider the following

```
vector <- c(100,100000,100,10000000,NA,NA)
format(vector, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] "       100" "   100,000" "       100" "10,000,000" "        NA" "        NA"
```

I guess that `na.rm=TRUE` doesn't work for `format`. How to obtain the same result and filter out the NAs from the output?

EDIT: `vector` belongs to an object (a graph) and I can't modify it's length. Also I need the object coming out from `format()` to have the same length of the input object.

Comment: Use `na.omit` on `vector`?

Comment: Use `gsub` on it after the fact?... `gsub( "NA" , "" , format(vector, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE ) )`

Answer (score 1):

I use this subset `vector <- vector[!is.na(vector)]` and then you can apply the format `format(vector, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
ifelse(
    is.na(vector),
    "",
    format(vector, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE)
)
```

or

```
replace(
     format(vector, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE),
     is.na(vector),
     ""
)
```